# Strange issues with file name and Xcode sim vs. ios device

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I just spent a day trying to figure out why some simple code was not loading images from the resources folder. Just for kicks I went into the finder and renamed one of the files to exactly the same name and it loaded. Then I did the others - simply renaming them to the same name. I looked and there weren't any strange characters or whitespace before or after the file name. So now they all load fine into an array in the simulator. But now on my device, they aren't loaded into the array, returning "nil" and are throwing exceptions. I know that ios devices are case sensitive where the sim is not but I checked this and the naming is all fine. The only thing I can think of is that my images are named for retina (@2x~iphone) and my device is not. But I have images named the same way, for retina, and those load fine.

I am using imageWithContentsOfFile to load the images and also getting a memory warning after it tries to load the images. I am not sure if the memory warning is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be in your file naming. Remember that you should include both retina and non-retina graphics in your app. Seeing as you added "~iphone" I'm assuming this is a universal application so your images should be named as follows:

1. myImage~iphone.png
2. myImage@2x~iphone.png
3. myImage~ipad.png
4. myImage@2x~ipad.png

Then in your code you only reference the "myImage" part of the file name so iOS can sort the rest out for you.

For example:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```